# Inheritance issue with pointer definition

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following structure so that I can call the same functions on the elements of `vector<Obj<T>*>` which will contain some `Obj1`, `Obj2`, `Obj3` or `Obj4`.

`Obj3` and `Obj4` are defined by other objects (1 & 2), and they need to call those functions on a const Obj1, or const Obj2.

The issue is in `Obj666`, pObj doesn't seem to point to `o1_unit`.
I would declare and define a `static Obj1<double>  = o1_unit(Obj1<double>(1.0))` and pass that pointer to it in Obj3, but I can't because of templates.

Is that method any good ? Any other way to achieve this ?

```
template <typename T>
class Obj   
{
    public:
    T a;

    public:
    Obj(T a_ = 0) : a(a_) {}

    virtual void fun() const = 0;

};

template <typename T>
class Obj1 : public Obj<T>
{
    public:
    T a1;

    public:
    // Obj1(T a1) : Obj<T>(a1) {} EDIT
    Obj1(T a1_) : Obj<T>(a1_), a1(a1_) {} 
    void fun() const
    { std::cout << a1 << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T>
class Obj2 : public Obj<T>
{
    public:
    T a2;

    public:
//  Obj2(T a2) : Obj<T>(a2) {}   EDIT
Obj2(T a2_) : Obj<T>(a2_), a2(a2_) {}

    void fun() const
    { std::cout << a2 << std::endl;}
};

template <typename T>
class Obj666 : public Obj<T>
{
    public:
    Obj<T> *pObj; // need pointers because Obj3 uses an Obj1 but other subclasses could use Obj2 ...
    T a666;

    public:
    Obj666(Obj<T>* pO) : Obj<T>(0), pObj(pO) {}
    Obj666(Obj<T>* pO, T a666_) : Obj<T>(0), pObj(pO), a666(a666_) {}

    virtual void fun() const
    { pObj->fun();
        std::cout << a666 << std::endl; 
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Obj3 : public Obj666<T>
{
    public:
    Obj3() : Obj666<T>(&o1_unit), o1_unit(Obj1<T>(1.0)) {}
    Obj3(T a666_) : Obj666<T>(&o1_unit, a666_), o1_unit(Obj1<T>(1.0)) {}

    void fun() const
    { (this->pObj)->fun();
        std::cout << "and something else from Obj3" << std::endl;
    }

    public:
        Obj1<T> o1_unit; // Obviously, I would do without it, but I can't declare a static Obj1<T> o1_unit = Obj1<T>(1.0), because template..
};

template <typename T>
class Obj4 : public Obj666<T>
{
    public:
    Obj4() : Obj666<T>(&o2_unit), o2_unit(Obj2<T>(10.0)) {}
    Obj4(T a666_) : Obj666<T>(&o2_unit, a666_), o2_unit(Obj2<T>(10.0)) {}

    void fun() const
    { (this->pObj)->fun();
        std::cout << "and something else from Obj4" << std::endl;
    }

    public:
        Obj2<T> o2_unit; // Obviously, I would do without it, but I can't declare a static Obj1<T> o1_unit = Obj1<T>(1.0), because template..

};

/// main.cpp
Obj3<double> o3(5);
Obj4<double> o4(13);

std::vector<Obj<T>*> objs;

objs.push_back(&o3);
objs.push_back(&o4);

objs[0]->fun(); // I'd like to call o1_unit->fun() so result 1 and 10
objs[1]->fun(); // but I have random numbers (2.0887e-317, 6.95324e-310 ..)
                // Same if I remove Obj3->fun, it calls Obj666->fun, but still no "1"
```

Comment: You're not showing real code. `std::vector<Obj<T>*> objs;` in `main()` would not compile.

Comment: `a1` and `a2` are never initialized, that's the reason of the random numbers you are seeing. It is not clear what kind of problem you have because of templates. Can you show the static definition you attempted to use?

Comment: Obj1, Obj2, Obj3,  Obj4, Obj666 - **What does it mean**? What are you trying to achieve? Looks like it could be done in <20% of the code

Comment: @n.m Right, made edits and it works. Shame cause my real code has seg faults and I was hoping that bit of code would be the cause .. About the static definition, `static Obj1<double> = o1_unit(Obj1<double>(1.0))` works, but I need it templated. Which isn't possible, I think.

Comment: @user2287453 A class template can have a static data member, if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Angew, How would it look like ? In Obj1 `{ static Obj1 o1_unit; };` and outside the class, `template <typename T> Obj1<T> o1_unit = Obj1<T>(1.0);` ? That doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You just missed the qualification outside the class: `template <typename T> Obj1<T> Obj1<T>::o1_unit(1.0);`

Comment: @Angew You just made my day my good sir ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `Obj1` does not initialise `a1` to anything. DTTO for `Obj2` and `a2`.

Comment: Right, made edits and it works. Shame cause my real code has seg faults and I was hoping that bit of code would be the cause ..